# How to hide/encrypt the ajax requests from network tab in google and other browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, video, jwplayer

I am working on jwplayer and I just want to hide/encrypt the ajax requests that are sent by jwplayer to play the video. The reason is this when jwplayer send request it contains video id and I don't want to reveal it because it is streaming from google drive and any one can leach the same video. Is there any method to hide/encrypt ajax calls from console?

I have tried clear console method console.clear(); but it clears console not network tab.

Answer (score 3):

As Max says you can't hide requests and/or stop someone from capturing any video which you download to your site.

The usual solution is to encrypt the video so it can't be viewed or played without a key.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code doesn't have access to network tab. Network tab shows requests/responses client browser sends. Even if you somehow manage to hide your requests from browsers network tab, client still can see req/res via tools like wireshark.
2. So you need to introduce some middle-ware between jwplayer and google drive, that will be responsible for securely fetching videos from google drive and serving them to jwplayer without exposing internal id's.

Comment: 1-I don't care about wireshark but I need to hide from network tab.
2-what kind of middle-ware?

Comment: 1. You can't. Browser doesn't provide any API for this, and it's pointless hiding req/res from network tab, as it's anyway easy accessible by client)
2. it could be any kind of backed, that will serve links to video or video itself by title or external id, hiding google drive id from client